Where does this whitespace above my faded TikZ image come from?
I'm trying to embed an image that fades towards the bottom. That works so far, but between the image and the text above it is some empty space (a couple of lines high) that I can't explain.
Here is my code (all texts replaced with random stuff, but it's the entire tex-file):
\subsection{My Subsection}

Go to \textit{Menu} $\rightarrow$ \textit{Submenu} and do something \colorbox{gray!15}{important} 
using \colorbox{gray!15}{something like this}: \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\imgwidth{1.0\textwidth}
    \def\imgratio{0.7}

    \def\imgheight{\imgwidth * \imgratio}

    \path (0,0) rectangle (\imgwidth,\imgheight);

    \node[scope fading=south, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=south] 
        at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth]{img/my_image.png}};
\end{tikzpicture} \\

To find out more, go \href{https://iwantmore.url}{there}.

The result:

I'm assuming that the issue lies with the rectangle I'm creating for the fading effect, but I can't tell what exactly goes wrong with it.

This is due to the \path rectangle. It seems your picture ratio is not 0.7.

You're right! I set the ratio to 0.6 and it jumped up immediately.

You should provide the right aspect ratio or even better just put the node in the tikzpicture (without the first 4 lines):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \subsection{My Subsection}
  
  Go to \textit{Menu} $\rightarrow$ \textit{Submenu} and do something \colorbox{gray!15}{important} 
  using \colorbox{gray!15}{something like this}:
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\imgwidth{1.0\textwidth}
%      %%% this part can be removed %%%
%    \def\imgratio{0.9} % change the value here to test with .9, the rectangle is higher than the picture
%    
%    \def\imgheight{\imgwidth * \imgratio}
%    
%    \path (0,0) rectangle (\imgwidth,\imgheight);
%    %%%%%%% end %%%%%
    \node[scope fading=south, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=south] 
    at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  
  To find out more, go \href{https://iwantmore.url}{there}.
  
\end{document}



As NBur correctly noticed, the issue was with the image ratio, 0.7 was too high.
I changed it to 0.5 (which is actually smaller than the real ratio) and the image jumped up and closed the gap.
